# Step by Step instructions to install HDF5 on Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, hdf5

I need a spreadsheet support in Tkinter. To install a module tkintertable available on GitHub, it requires a library called tables which in turn requires HDF5.

For installing HDF5, I downloaded it's file below
https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.10/hdf5-1.10.1/src/CMake-hdf5-1.10.1.zip
for building it through CMake. After putting it in a folder I ran one of the batch files but it shows the following error:

. Size of output: 0K
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
Error(s) when building project

[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
   1 Compiler errors

1 Compiler warnings
Test project …../GUI/CMake-hdf5-1.10.1/build
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
No tests were found!!!

Would someone mention step by step process to install hdf5 in windows, would appreciate it a lot.